# Преобразование речи в текст

Tags: android

Как можно преобразовать речь в текст в android? Например удерживаешь кнопку говоришь что-то, и твоя речь преобразуется в текст. Может есть встроенные механизмы для этого в андроид, может библиотеки, а может нейронные сети)

Comment: Есть такая возможность. Вот, например, статья с примером: http://stackandroid.com/tutorial/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/

Comment: Спасибо. А мне вот интересно.. различные асистенты типа Алиса от яндекс работают по таким же базовым принципам (вы что-то сказали программа распознала текст и голосом дала заранее заготовленный ответ) или там что-то другое?

Comment: Не думаю, что они что-то меняли в этом плане. Думаю, они сосредоточились на разборе скорее текста, чем голоса.